# Am I able to go on mash up packs using pc

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Am I able to join XBox worlds, like cool mash up packs?

Answer (score 1):

(If you're talking about joining an Xbox world from PC Minecraft, or vice versa):

**TL;DR: No**

They are coded in different languages, and have significant differences in the actual workings, so even making the two versions compatible would be difficult.  This is the same for all of them (console/PC/pocket edition).